# Nested IF ELSE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I want to execute below stored procedure, but it gives me an error. Inside flag 1 after updating the order table I want to check another condition and if that's true then I want to run another update query. I tried this in SQL Server with temporary tables and it worked. please help me.

Error is below:

> Script line: 4    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'FROM product PR
>           INNER JOIN (SELECT PR.ID AS ProductID, (PR.Quantity - OD.Qu' at line 35

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `onlineshop`.`USP_Public_SaveOrder` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `USP_Public_SaveOrder`(IN pint_Flag INT,INOUT pint_ID BIGINT,IN pint_Status INT,IN pint_CustomerID BIGINT,IN pint_ShippingAddressID BIGINT,IN pint_BillingAddresID BIGINT, IN pdec_ShippingCharge DECIMAL(18,2),IN pdec_Tax DECIMAL(18,2),IN pdec_Total DECIMAL(18,2),IN pdte_TransactionDate DATETIME)
BEGIN
IF(pint_Flag=0) THEN
    INSERT INTO orderheader(Status,
                                            CustomerID,
                                            ShippingAddressID,
                                            BillingAddressID,
                                            ShippingCharge,
                                            Tax,
                                            Total,
                                            TransactionDate)
                            VALUES (pint_Status,
                                            pint_CustomerID,
                                            pint_ShippingAddressID,
                                            pint_BillingAddresID,
                                            pdec_ShippingCharge,
                                            pdec_Tax,
                                            pdec_Total,
                                            pdte_TransactionDate);
        SET pint_ID=LAST_INSERT_ID();

ELSEIF(pint_Flag=1) THEN
    UPDATE orderheader
    SET     Status = pint_Status,
                CustomerID = pint_CustomerID,
                ShippingAddressID = pint_ShippingAddressID,
                BillingAddressID = pint_BillingAddresID,
                ShippingCharge = pdec_ShippingCharge,
                Tax = pdec_Tax,
                Total = pdec_Total,
                TransactionDate = pdte_TransactionDate
    WHERE   ID=pint_ID;
  IF(pint_Status=2) THEN
    UPDATE product SET Quantity = A.remain
    FROM product PR
    INNER JOIN (SELECT PR.ID AS ProductID, (PR.Quantity - OD.Quantity) AS remain
              FROM product P
              INNER JOIN orderdetail OD ON OD.ProductID = P.ID AND OD.OrderID = pint_ID) A ON PR.ID = A.ProductID
  ELSE
    RETURN
  END IF;
END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a semi-colon before the last "ELSE".

Comment: i added a semi-colon. but still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `UPDATE` block as follows and try it.

```
IF(pint_Status=2) THEN
    UPDATE product PR
    INNER JOIN (SELECT PR.ID AS ProductID, (PR.Quantity - OD.Quantity) AS remain
                FROM product P
                INNER JOIN orderdetail OD ON OD.ProductID = P.ID AND OD.OrderID = pint_ID
               ) A ON PR.ID = A.ProductID
    SET PR.Quantity = A.remain;
ELSE
    RETURN
END IF;
```

Comment: seems its working. i have written a RETURN in else part. so this time issue is that. actually i dont need else part here. can i just remove that else from the code...? or what should i write in else part here... thanks for your help :)

Comment: Incase if you want to terminate the stored procedure execution and return any boolean or expression you can use [RETURN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/return.html), otherwise simply skip the ELSE block

Comment: `This statement (RETURN) is not used in stored procedures, triggers, or events. The LEAVE statement can be used to exit a stored program of those types.`, see [14.6.5.7 RETURN Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/return.html).

Answer (score 1):

Check the syntax of the UPDATE statement: [14.2.11 UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html).

```sql
.
.
.
UPDATE product SET Quantity = A.remain
FROM product PR
   INNER JOIN (SELECT PR.ID AS ProductID, (PR.Quantity - OD.Quantity) AS remain
               FROM product P
                 INNER JOIN orderdetail OD ON
                   OD.ProductID = P.ID AND
                   OD.OrderID = pint_ID
              ) A ON PR.ID = A.ProductID -- ; <- Add semicolon
.
.
.
/*ELSE
    RETURN*/
```

Stored procedures do not need `RETURN`.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's `UPDATE` syntax does not use the `FROM` keyword. If you want to specify an alias for the table you're updating, just put it after the `UPDATE tablename` clause. And in your subquery you should be using the alias `P`, not `PR`.

```
UPDATE PRODUCT AS PR
INNER JOIN (SELECT P.ID AS ProductID, (P.Quantity - OD.Quantity) AS remain
          FROM product P
          INNER JOIN orderdetail OD ON OD.ProductID = P.ID AND OD.OrderID = pint_ID) A ON PR.ID = A.ProductID
SET PR.Quantity = A.remain
```

There's actually no need to use the subquery, just join `PRODUCT` with `orderdetail` directly.

```
UPDATE PRODUCT AS PR
INNER JOIN orderdetail AS OD ON OD.ProductID = PR.ID
SET PR.Quantity = PR.Quantity - OD.Quantity
WHERE OD.OrderID = pintID
```

Comment: im new to mySql. previously i used sqlserver. so i have less knowledge in mySQL syntax. your query is working. thanks for it :)

Comment: Change `P.ID` by `PR.ID`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I caught all of them.